# Print the value of a multidimensional array with the output as compatible matlab code

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

For matrices with dimensions equal or less then 2 the command is:

For instance:

```
>> mat2str(ones(2,2))

ans =

[1 1;1 1]
```

However, [as the help states](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2str.html), this does not work for higher dimensions:

```
>> mat2str(rand(2,2,2))
Error using mat2str (line 49)
Input matrix must be 2-D.
```

How to output matrices with higher dimensions than 2 with that is code compatible, without resorting to custom made for loops?

Comment: Well I just learned a new command! Anyhow, I doubt that it's possible as there is no separator for third dimensions (like the comma and semicolon are for 2D). You *could* use `sprintf` with a `cat(3, ` at the beginning to concatenate all of the 2D arrays together into a 3D array.

Comment: It was not trivial to find the command :). I did not get it how your suggestion with `sprintf` would work.

Comment: `mat2str` is a wrapper for `sprintf`, and utilizes loops. There's no reason to avoid them. But, as @Suever says, there's no way to enter a 3D+ array with the same syntax.

Comment: @hakanc Sorry, it is a little difficult to describe in a comment. I have added an answer and demo below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't directly possible because there is no built-in character to represent concatenation in the third dimension (an analog to the comma and semicolon in 2D). One potential workaround for this would be to perform `mat2str` on all "slices" in the third dimension and wrap them in a call to [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) which, when executed, would concatenate all of the 2D matrices in the third dimension to recreate your input matrix.

```
M = reshape(1:8, [2 2 2]);

arrays = arrayfun(@(k)mat2str(M(:,:,k)), 1:size(M, 3), 'uni', 0);
result = ['cat(3', sprintf(', %s', arrays{:}), ')'];

result =

    'cat(3, [1 3;2 4], [5 7;6 8])'

isequal(eval(result), M)

    1
```

**UPDATE**

After thinking about this some more, a more elegant solution is to flatten the input matrix, run `mat2str` on that, and then in the string used to recreate the data, we utilize `reshape` combined with the original dimensions to provide a command which will recreate the data. This will work for any dimension of data.

```
result = sprintf('reshape(%s, %s);', mat2str(M(:)), mat2str(size(M)));
```

So for the following 4D input

```
M = randi([0 9], 1, 2, 3, 4);
result = sprintf('reshape(%s, %s);', mat2str(M(:)), mat2str(size(M)));

    'reshape([6;9;4;6;5;2;6;1;7;2;1;7;2;1;6;2;2;8;3;1;1;3;8;5], [1 2 3 4]);'
```

Now if we reconstruct the data using this generated string, we can ensure that we get the correct data back.

```
Mnew = eval(result);
size(Mnew)

    1   2   3   4

isequal(Mnew, M)

    1
```

By specifying both the class and precision inputs to `mat2str`, we can even better approximate the input data including floating point numbers.

```
M = rand(1,2,3,4,5);
result = sprintf('reshape(%s, %s);', mat2str(M(:),64,'class'), mat2str(size(M)));

isequal(eval(result), M)

    1
```

Comment: I up voted the answer because it is a solution for 3D matrices, although I cannot clearly see how it is can be extended to higher dimensions. Coming from Python, I cannot really understand how one cannot define arrays with higher dimensions in a consistent way in matlab.

Comment: @hakanc I updated my solution with a more brief solution that will work for any dimension of data.

Comment: @hakanc *one cannot define arrays with higher dimensions*, yes you can! but in a string? why in a string? printed? Why would you print a 5 dimensional matrix? Creating them is easy, `rand(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)` works.....

Comment: Well done. Good job on creating a string which can be re-evaluated to the original matrix ... (_although I fail to imagine in which cases you would want to do that_)

Comment: @Hoki The only real world use case I can think of for this would be if you need to create an ascii file which can be reloaded to recreate an N-dimensional array. For example if you wanted to programmatically create an m-file that (when executed) could return a 3D matrix (an RGB image for example) and you had the image as a 3D matrix in your current workspace.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Let's imagine that I have a 16 x 16 x 3 icon that I want to be returned by a function `getSueverIcon()` and I don't want to store the binary image file in version control. You would want some way (given an image file) to create a string which you can dump into an m-file to create the same image.

Comment: @Hoki, in addition to Suever point, [testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) of the code yields situations where one wants to compare the return value to a known matrix, without storing data in binary formats due to source control.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, what I meant was higher dimension matrices with user defined values, e.g. `[[[3, 1], [3, 1]], [[4, 3], [2, 4]]]` in python. How is that written in one line in matlab?